# HTTPGet using Auth Token throwing error code 403

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to get a response from a URI with an Auth token.

```java
public void executeReponse(){

    URI uri = new URIBuilder()
            .setScheme("http")
            .setHost(<host>)
            .setPath(<path>)
            .setParameter("token", Auth.getAuthToken(URL, UNAME, PWD))
            .build();
    //Auth.getAuthToken() returns my authToken

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpGet);
    int responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    System.out.println("Request Url: " + httpGet.getURI());
    System.out.println("Response Code: " + responseCode);

}
```

Upon executing this, I get the following error

```
Response Code: 403
```

I have provided the token with the URI but still it is not authorizing.

Can someone help me out with this

Comment: The answer depends on the API you are trying to access. You are probably not passing the authorization token in the format expected by that API.

Comment: i think you GET when POST or POST when GET request is allowed .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code `403 Forbidden` means: The server knows who you are, but doesn't think you have access to the resource you are trying to request (for example: if user A tries to access user B's private Facebook message).

This is in contrast to `401 Unauthorized` which means: the server doesn't know who you are, and the resource you are requesting requires you to be authorized.

Make sure that you have the correct credentials for the service you are trying to connect to. If you are also developing that service, check your access permissions on that resource.